# Vaadin-SpringBootServletInitializer vs AppShellConfigurator .What is valid for production build on external Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm building my project with Spring Boot and when uploading to Tomcat as a .war it was throwing errors.
In any case what fixed it is to change

```
  public class Application implements AppShellConfigurator {
```

to

```
 public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {
```

I've used a sampler from start.vaadin.com v22 to build upon which came by default with the

> Application implements AppShellConfigurator

Like this it was running fine inside Intellij with the embedded Tomcat but when deploying to a standalone/external one , I had to change that to the latter.
Is that required ? if yes then the docs should be updated because at

https://vaadin.com/docs/v22/flow/production/production-build

there's no mention of it.

Comment: Because that is related to spring Boot and not Vaadin, and for Spring Boot that is documented. Most people use the embedded Tomcat instead of deploying to an external Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

As M. Deinum said this is related to Spring Boot.

Usually you run the Spring Boot Application as an executable JAR. But If you want to run it as a WAR inside a Tomcat you have to use SpringBootServletInitializer.

> The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a
> SpringBootServletInitializer subclass and override its configure
> method. Doing so makes use of Spring Framework’s servlet 3.0 support
> and lets you configure your application when it is launched by the
> servlet container. Typically, you should update your application’s
> main class to extend SpringBootServletInitializer...

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment

Comment: I see,but shouldn't it be mentioned in Vaadin's official documentation as a hint to those going that way?

Comment: It's mentioned: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/spring-boot